# Forcing modules to have a specific function. eg implement an interface?

Tags: javascript

Simple in java, but how do I ensure the modules that are registering with my event bus for topic notifications have the required callback method on them?

All my modules are following the revealing module pattern and as such are defined like the following

```
namespace = (function() {

    //Private stuff 

    return {
        method1 : method1
    }
})();
```

I just need to ensure the module has a notify method on it which takes a single argument.  The module can be responsible for unmarshalling the payload data into the format it is expecting

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*I really want to help but I'm not sure I understand your terminology. I'll answer based on my limited understanding and adjust as necessary*

Sounds to me like you want to make sure the object returned has a property called `notify` on it, which is a function that accepts one function parameter only. If this is correct, there are two places you can ensure all modules meet your requirement.

1. **Inside the Event Bus**

If you wrote the event bus, you can write a few lines of code inside it to make sure that if a module doesn't come with the 'notify' property on it, the event bus will not subscribe the module to the event. Something like this:

```
if( typeof module.notify !== 'function' ){

    // do error handling then ...
    return false;
}
```

2. **External Function for Registering Modules to Event Bus**

If you didn't write the event bus, you can create an external function that is responsible for ensuring the standard. Think of it as a wrapper around #1.

```
function registerToEventBus( module, event ){

    if( typeof module.notify !== 'function' ){
        // do error handling then ...
        return false;
    }

    // register event to event bus then ...
    return true;
}
```

**Personally I'd recommend using #2**

- That way you wouldn't need to know a thing about the event bus itself to implement this.
- You get the added benefit of being able to keep the event bus strictly for events and not complicate it by adding the module format enforcement into it.
- You will be able to take the event bus as is to another project, drop it in and edit your enforcer function to meet this project's specificiations with absolutely no risk of breaking the event bus accidentally.

I hope this helps. If there's any place I misunderstood you, let me know and I'll give it my best shot to fix.

Comment: This is ideal.  I just need to make sure that a registered listener can be called back without issue when an event arrives that matches the supplied topic.  I will probably go with #1